# Membership Management Customization: Assessment Sign up

Tags: civimember, registration

Member sign up
I want a process that allows for association members to apply for membership, register and submit documentation related to their certifications .
These then need to be assessed and approved by administrators

Can the CiviCRM system accommodate that?

Regards
Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew - what CMS are you using? I can suggest a solution using Drupal webforms. Others would know better if it can be done via Caldera if you are on WP

Comment: Hi Pete - I'm currently using Wordpress. Havent used Drupal or Joomla in years.

Answer (score 2):

There is an approach whereby you set up a Membership Status of 'waiting approval' that kicks in at 'join date' and puts the membership in to a non-current status (overridden) - there are some old threads around that may give more pointers eg

- https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=25771.0.html
- [membership approval](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24590/membership-approval)
- https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=33584.0.html

IN terms of providing documentation, this can be done via a CiviCRM Profile

Answer (score 0):

The type of process you are requesting is actually available through events and is called the [**Participant Approval Process**](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/online-event-registration/#participant-approval), but as you know, online membership sign-up is handled via contribution pages so it would indeed require customization. You may wish to reach out to several [**developers**](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) to obtain quotes for this work.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: Thanks Tamar - but that feature looks like its related to CiviEvents?